# SVM classification metrics are all 1 although there are mistakes in classification

Tags: classification, python, svm

Here is a fitted [`LinearSVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) model showing the learned separating hyperplane for my training samples:

[image]

And when I use [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) for the training samples, I get below table where all metrics are 1.

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       False       1.00      1.00      1.00      1760
        True       1.00      1.00      1.00      3296

    accuracy                           1.00      5056
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      5056
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      5056
```

Why is this the case? How can I get metrics reflecting the fact that there are misclassified samples?

I also tried a logistic regression classifier, and again the metrics are all 1 from that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results look to be rounded to 2 decimal places so my guess is that the numbers aren't exactly 1.00 but close to 1.00 and rounded up. As you can see the majority of the data points are correctly clustered.

Comment: Wow, this was a simple and powerful response, thanks. I increased the `digits` parameter in `classification_report` and saw that it was indeed 0.99.... not exactly 1.